# Can't make phone calls to numbers with asterisk

Tags: swift, nsurl

I'm trying to make a phonecall from the app, nevertheless the number have an * ... So it doesn't work. If I delete the *, it works just well, but not as intented.

```
    let phoneNumber = "tel://*000000"

    if let url = NSURL(string: phoneNumber) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Simply remove the `*` then.

Comment: @Osuka42:  From looking through Apple Docs - there is no reference to allowing use of the * character as part of the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.
Apple doesn't allow to make phonecalls with the * character

> ... To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number. ...